# Nested Routes, Creating a Vacancy that belongs to a Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

my first question on here. Im quite stuck, im trying to have a link create  a vacancy. But some reason all i can get is nil for Vacancy.project... i've tried params[:project_id].to_i in the create method and that gets me 0, but the project id for this case is 156, and on the view params.inspect gives just that.

I've also tried nothing in my new controller, and loads of different attempts to read the session info. The the position code is just that a vacancies builds a position too, but that shouldn't affect much, would it?

Any ideas?

Vacancy controller

```
def new

 @vacancy = Vacancy.new

 @vacancy.position = Position.new

 @vacancy.project_id = params[:project_id]


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @vacancy }

end
end
```

The routes im using

```
  resources :projects do

      resources :vacancies

  end
```

the link im using:

```
      <%= link_to "Add Vacancy", new_project_vacancy_path(@project)  %>
```

models
      project...
      has_many :vacancies

&
      Vacancy.....
    belongs_to :project

Answer (score 0):

To an ultra dry implementation, you could do it like this:

```
    class VacanciesController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :load_project, :load_vacancy

      def new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        if @vacancy.update_attributes( params[:vacancy] )
          flash[:notice] = 'Vacancy successfully created/updated'
          redirect_to project_vacancies_path( @project )
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      alias :update :create

      protected

      def load_vacancy
        @vacancy = if params[:id].blank?
          @project.vacancies.build
        else
          @project.vacancies.find(params[:id])
        end
      end

      def load_project
        @project = Project.find( params[:project_id] )
      end

    end
```